# Unix "ln -s" command not permitted in OSX El Capitan Beta3

Tags: unix, url

I was installing nodejs for Symphony when I hit an "Operation not permitted" error.  Anyone know why this happened?

> MacBook-Pro-de-XXX:~ XXX$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
>
> Password:
>
> ln: /usr/bin/node: Operation not permitted

Comment: First check whether /usr/bin/node is already set up.  If you want to change it, you can use ln -sf to force the symlink.

Comment: MacBook-Pro-de-XXX:~ XXX$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node

Comment: ls -la /usr/bin/node

Comment: MacBook-Pro-de-XXX:~ XXX$ ls -la /usr/bin/node
ls: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This is the so called "rootless" mode in the new version of OS X. It effectively makes certain system directories read-only (even for admins). "/usr" is one of those protected directories (the only subdirectory that is excluded from this rule is "/usr/local")

One can disable this rootless mode with the following commands:

```
$ sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"
$ sudo reboot
```

But this is not recommended! The best practice is to install custom stuff to "/usr/local" only.

---

Update (27-Oct-15): **10.11 (El Capitan) Public Release**

Please note that the above described workaround will **not** work with the public release of El Capitan anymore as Apple has changed things around.

The proper way to disable the "rootless" mode (aka System Integrity Protection, "SIP") is to boot temporarily into Recover Mode (hold Command+R during boot) and use the `csrutil disable` command (or `csrutil enable` to reenable) from the Terminal. The Terminal is reachable via the menu of the Installer that launches in Recovery Mode.

Comment: Might not be advisable, but for now MacTeX seems to expect `/usr/texbin`, so away we go!

Comment: Modifying NVRAM to disable rootless mode doesn't work on El Capitan from (at least) the GM version forward. Check this answer for the method that works in the version that is out now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590053/copying-file-under-root-got-failed-in-os-x-el-capitan-10-11/32590885#32590885

Comment: This not worked for me too.

Comment: still give me `Operation not permitted`

Comment: My workaround was to install to /usr/local/bin

Answer (score -2):

In my version of El Capitan the `/bin` directory did not exist :

`/usr/local/bin`

So, the fix was :

`mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`

The `-p` flag will create the dir (and incidentally any dirs in the full path) if it does not exist.

Then you can create symlinks & copy apps to `/usr/local/bin` because `/usr/local` not part of the "rootless" mode.

Comment: It does not help to solve the issue. Sometimes you just need symlinks in /usr/bin and cannot avoid that.